# загрузка .obj файла

Tags: java, 3d

делаю 3д движок без сторонних библиотек. сделал метод загрузки файлов формата .obj но он очень медленный.

```
public void loadObj(String path)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            Vertex v1 = null, v2 = null, v3 = null;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            String res2 = null;
            String[] text1 = null;
            while(scanner.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] text = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                if(text[0].equals("f"))
                {
                    for(int i = 1; i < text.length; i++)
                    {
                        String[] result = text[i].split("/");
                        
                        String currentLine = result[0];
                        
                        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file);
                        
                        int line = 0;
                        
                        while(scanner2.hasNextLine())
                        {
                            res2 = scanner2.nextLine();
                            line++;
                            if(line == Integer.valueOf(currentLine))
                            {
                                text1 = res2.split(" ");
                                scanner2.close();
                                break;
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(i == 1)
                        {
                            v1 = new Vertex(Double.valueOf(text1[1]), Double.valueOf(text1[2]), Double.valueOf(text1[3]));
                        }
                        
                        else if(i == 2)
                        {
                            v2 = new Vertex(Double.valueOf(text1[1]), Double.valueOf(text1[2]), Double.valueOf(text1[3]));
                        }
                        else if(i == 3)
                        {
                            v3 = new Vertex(Double.valueOf(text1[1]), Double.valueOf(text1[2]), Double.valueOf(text1[3]));
                            tris.add(new Triangle(v1, v2, v3));
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

код сначала достает вершины из строки с началом "f" а затем ищет эти вершины и "складывает" из них полигоны, которые потом добавляет в массив. можно ли как-то оптимизировать данный код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача имеет по идее сложность `O(n)`, а вы из нее сделали `O(n2)` - в цикле на каждую строку файла читаете свой файл еще раз...

Я бы на вашем месте считывал бы все в одном проходе вставляя вершины/полигоны во что-то типа `HashMap<Integer, List<Vertex>>` - где `Integer` - номер строки (идентификатора полигона) где встречается описание узла, а `List<Vertex>` список узлов, то есть код выглядел бы приблизительно так:

```
Map<Integer, List<Vertex>> vertices = new HashMap<Integer, List<Vertex>>(); //инициализация
int line; //идентификатор полигона (возможно номер строки?)
List<Vertex> listAtLine = vertices.get(line); //массив вершин относящийся к строке line
if (listAtLine == null)
    listAtLine = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
//blah-blah
//....
// далее где-то в коде когда требуется инициализация Vertex
listAtLine.add(new Vertex(...)); //прочитанная из файла вершина
vertices.put(line, listAtLine);  //записываем в мап
```

В итоге после прохождения всего файла у вас останется `Map` содержащий список всех вершин привязанный к идентификатору полигона. Далее останется получить список полигонов, через:

```
vertices.values();
```

Приведенный код не руководство копипейст, а всего лишь идея, как за один проход составить полный список всех полигонов.

Comment: точно) спасибо!